# iTextSharp VB.Net - Fixing the formatting of my table to properly display in PDF

Tags: vb.net, pdf, datagridview, itext

So far I keep getting PDF's life these:

[image]

I just want to have a PDF file that displays them like an Excel would. Example:
[image]

How do I make my iTextSharp values to display properly? I just want my words to line up straight instead of cutting them in halves. My button code is shown below: A4.Rotate as suggested by @JoshPart

```
Dim pdfTable As New PdfPTable(DataGridView1.ColumnCount)

    'Add Title of PDF
    Dim cell1 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(StudentToolStripMenuItem.Text))
    cell1.Colspan = 28
    cell1.Border = 0
    cell1.HorizontalAlignment = 1
    pdfTable.AddCell(cell1)

    'Creating iTextSharp Table from the DataTable data
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3
    pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 100
    pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1


    'Adding Header row
    For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
        Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(column.HeaderText))
        cell.BackgroundColor = New iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(240, 240, 240)
        pdfTable.AddCell(cell)
    Next

    'Adding DataRow
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If row.IsNewRow = False Then
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString())
            Next
        End If
    Next

    'Exporting to PDF
    Dim folderPath As String = "C:\Mickosis\Class Manager\PDFs\"
    If Not Directory.Exists(folderPath) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath)
    End If
    Using stream As New FileStream(folderPath & StudentToolStripMenuItem.Text & ".pdf", FileMode.Create)
        Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate, 5.0F, 5.0F, 5.0F, 5.0F)
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream)
        pdfDoc.Open()
        pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable)
        pdfDoc.Close()
        stream.Close()
    End Using

    MsgBox("PDF Created", , msgboxtitle)
```

Comment: You know that you have specified a 200% wide table, right?

Comment: Yes I am kinda guilty of that, sorry but when I put it at about 50, all the letters are aligned vertically. How do I fix that? @ChrisHaas

Comment: Unless you create a really wide page you'll have to split the columns in several pages. See `PdfTable.WriteSelectedRows()`.

Comment: Hi @PauloSoares, can you specify a little bit more? I have no clue in manipulating iTextSharp stuff, I can't even put a title header in my pdf lol sorry

Comment: `WidthPercentage` lets you set how much of the page the table will use. 100 will be the whole page. 200 are two pages. As Paulo said, you need to define the page size to see how many columns you can set. Now, the `PdfPTable` constructor has an overload that receives a `float` array with wich you can define the column widths.

Comment: Hello @JoshPart I seem to get the `WidthPercentage` now, and I have put it to 100. Is the page size you are referring to the `(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F)` one? This is what I have in my code... Right now they are appearing vertically

Comment: Yeah, that one. Try with `PageSize.A4.Rotate`. That way your document will have horizontal orientation.

Comment: @JoshPart thanks for your suggestions! It looks a little bit better, but now it looks like [this:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_CYqm8bmsR1SnltbkNKV3JyVFk/view?usp=sharing) how do I make it display on a straight line only/it won't cut the names?

Comment: You've got three options as far as I can. 1) Drop the font size of the header, 2) Use a larger page size, 3) use multiple pages for your columns. Each has their own pluses and minuses.

Comment: Maybe 4) Write vertically the column headers and the values for the first 3 columns

Comment: @ChrisHaas I can't seem to find the font size for the headers, can you give me an example code for any of those 3? Sorry to bother

Comment: @JoshPart I think the column headers can be written vertically, but the first 3 columns needs to be horizontal to be read properly?

Comment: The `Phrase` class has an [overloaded constructor](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/Phrase.cs#l163), one version of which takes a `Font` object that you can set the font and size.

Comment: I still haven't found a solution, the Font doesn't seem to help @ChrisHaas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A4 paper rotated is 280 mm or 11 inches wide. You're trying to place 28 columns on it which means that each column can have 10 mm or 3/8 inches of space, and that doesn't include any cell padding or column borders. At a normal readable font size, as you've seen, you can only really fit 3 to 5 characters on a single line.

One option is to drop the font size, probably down to something that's not readable like 3 or 4.

```
Dim HeaderFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 4)
Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Your Text", HeaderFont))
```

However, a better option would be to just use a larger page size. You might be able to get away with A2 if you also drop the font size but you'll probably need to go to A1 or possibly A0 even.

```
Dim Doc As New Document(PageSize.A1.Rotate, 5.0F, 5.0F, 5.0F, 5.0F)
```

Of course, when you look at this on screen you're going to have to zoom in and when you print it you'll need to downsize to smaller paper and you probably won't be able to read it, but that's what 28 columns with really long text looks like.

The third option I talked about was to vertically split your table. Although possible, it is not automatic and can be very brittle if the length of your values change frequently. [Bruno has a great post on doing it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21508645/231316).

The fourth option that Josh Part talked about is to rotate your text or draw it vertically. You can see an example of [writing vertically here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=202) although that is pretty complicated. Rotating text, however, is actually really easy, you just set the `Rotation` property on your cell to a multiple of 90.

```
cell.Rotation = 90
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! Another quick question, I plan to separate the grades by period so I don't have to fit it all in one page. How do I make my program write a table and when the table is finish, create a new table in the next page and not directly below the first table?

Comment: Call `Doc.NewPage()` between the two tables.